# Command line data loading on Mac OS X

Tags: data-loader, mac-os-x

I've been using [Lexiloader](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/lexiloader/) on Mac OS X as a drop-in replacement for the windows-only Apex Data Loader, but it doesn't seem to include the `process` command that provides [command line support in ADL](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line).  Is there a Mac equivalent anywhere to Apex Data Loader's command line support?

Comment: Hopefully you'll get a good answer, but if not here are a couple of blog entries that might (or might not) help http://force201.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/running-the-apex-data-loader-on-a-mac/ http://force201.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/scripting-the-apex-data-loader-via-ant/.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Jitterbit Data Loader. It allows you to schedule jobs to run with no command line needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured out how to do this using Lexiloader, by referring to `process.bat` that comes with the official (Windows) Apex Data Loader, which just runs a Java class in the dataloader jar.

Here's a sample Windows command:

```
process confDir csvInsertArtist
```

And here's the equivalent OS X command line (assumes LexiLoader v.29 installed in /Applications, adjust path if you have another version/install location):

```
java -cp /Applications/LexiLoader_v29.app/Contents/Resources/Java/Dataloader.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=confDir com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner process.name=csvInsertArtist
```

Otherwise, everything works like the windows version - you use the same process-conf.xml file, etc.  Likewise, the `encrypt` command included with the Windows version can be run with:

```
java -cp /Applications/LexiLoader_v29.app/Contents/Resources/Java/Dataloader.jar com.salesforce.dataloader.security.EncryptionUtil
```

which will give you usage information.

Comment: Amazing! I've stored data loading resources in our git repo for client data loading jobs as follows:
gitRepo/dataloader/process-conf.xml, gitRepo/dataloader/mappings/mappingFile.sdl, gitRepo/dataloader/bin-mac/Dataloader.jar, gitRepo/dataloader/bin-win/process.bat

This way, you can use the same process-conf.xml and mapping files for the multiple platform executables.