# Using DataLoader (Command line) on Mac

Tags: data-loader, java, mac-os-x, dataloader-batch

Is it possible that Data Loader command line can work in os x?  After all it is "just java."  I'm sure some of the JDBC stuff might not work but is it possible that simple CSV extracts could work? I'm hoping that with the right shell scripts it can be done but if people know otherwise I won't waste my time. Thanks.

Comment: See also the answer for this question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30484/command-line-data-loading-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

I used it a while back ... not sure if it still works.  Here are some tools to use the Mac DataLoader from the command line.  https://github.com/sthiyaga/dataloader

Answer (score 0):

Command Line for Dataloader is not supported by Mac, only Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I get that it is not supported, I was asking if it is known to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does work.
I created tool a while back to help with it:
https://github.com/theswamis/dataloadercliq

Let me know if you run into any trouble.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the overview text in the answer as well as the link in case the link breaks.